# SpriteKIt - Dynamic object collides with wall and walks trough

Tags: objective-c, ios7, sprite-kit

I'm working over simple test game. I have dynamic object that collides with wall. If velocity of the dynamic object is high (I think this is the reason) object walks trough the wall. Does anybody knows how to fix this ?

Wall:

```
// Create wall ...
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 25, self.frame.size.height);
    SKNode *wallNode = [SKNode node];
    wallNode.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) + rect.size.width * 0.5,                                       250);
    wallNode.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:rect.size];
    wallNode.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
    wallNode.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = CollisionTypeNet;
    [self addChild:wallNode];
```

Player :

```
SKSpriteNode *player = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"player"];

player.name = playerCategoryName;

player.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:player.frame.size];
player.physicsBody.restitution = 0.1f;
player.physicsBody.friction = 0.0f;
player.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;

player.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = CollisionTypePlayer;
player.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = CollisionTypeNet ;
player.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = CollisionTypeWall;
[self addChild:player];
```

Comment: Hmmm without matching (nonzero) contact bitmasks there can be no collision. For high velocity use precise collision: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPhysicsBody/usesPreciseCollisionDetection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

High velocity "pass throughs" are a common issue. As Cocos stated, set the `usesPreciseCollisionDetection` to true for your player object.

You should also apply a speed cap to faster moving objects as `usesPreciseCollisionDetection` is not guaranteed to work on very fast moving objects.

You can apply a speed cap like this:

```
if(mySpriteA.physicsBody.velocity.dx > 50)
    mySpriteA.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(50, mySpriteA.physicsBody.velocity.dy);
if(mySpriteA.physicsBody.velocity.dx < -50)
    mySpriteA.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(-50, mySpriteA.physicsBody.velocity.dy);
if(mySpriteA.physicsBody.velocity.dy > 50)
    mySpriteA.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(mySpriteA.physicsBody.velocity.dx, 50);
if(mySpriteA.physicsBody.velocity.dy < -50)
    mySpriteA.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(mySpriteA.physicsBody.velocity.dx, -50);
```

Comment: how does one apply a speed cap?

Comment: Additional question on the topic. I update object position when "touchesMoved" I've logged velocity of the object and no matter what velocity is still dx : 0.0 and dy 0.0. Is the way I update object position right at all ?

Comment: @DeVladinci - I can't really say without seeing all the relevant code. The posted code for this question only shows node properties. I suggest you post it as a new question if the problem still persists in some other form or you run into another issue.